# JPA calling default constructor even during POST request

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I didn't had a default constructor in my entity class in the beginning. Eventually found out that JPA requires a default constructor in entity class so I made one.

After adding the default constructor, even during post requests, JPA keeps calling default constructor which leads to incorrect initialisation of properties. For example, if you see the property called **availableSeats**, it is initialised to 100, but during post request only default constructor is called which leads to initialisation of **availableSeats** to 0.

This is extremely weird and I don't understand what am I doing wrong here.

```
@Entity
public class Flight {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    
    @NotBlank(message = "Airline Name cannot be blank!")
    private String airlineName;

    @NotBlank(message = "From-Location cannot be blank!")
    private String fromLocation;

    @NotBlank(message = "To-Location cannot be blank!")
    private String toLocation;

    @NotBlank(message = "Airport Gate Number cannot be blank")
    private String gateNumber;

    // @NotBlank(message = "Boarding time cannot be blank")
    private ZonedDateTime dateTimeZone;

    private static final int INITIAL_SEAT_CAPACITY = 100;
    private int availableSeats;

    // constructor should not be able to set id
    public Flight(Long id, String airlineName, String fromLocation, String toLocation, String gateNumber, ZonedDateTime dateTimeZone, int availableSeats) {


        this.id = id;
        this.airlineName = airlineName;
        this.fromLocation = fromLocation;
        this.toLocation = toLocation;
        this.gateNumber = gateNumber;
        this.dateTimeZone = dateTimeZone;
        
        // setting up initial number of available seats
        this.availableSeats = INITIAL_SEAT_CAPACITY;
    }

    public Flight(){
    }

    // getters and setters        
}
```

Also adding FlightController.java code here

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/flights")
public class FlightController {   

    @Autowired
    FlightService flightService;

    @GetMapping(value = "/")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Flight>> getAllFlights(){
        return flightService.getAllFlights();
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/")
    public ResponseEntity<String> createFlight(@Valid @RequestBody Flight flight){
        return flightService.createFlight(flight);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Flight> getFlightById(@PathVariable Long id){
        return flightService.getFlightById(id);
    }

    @DeleteMapping(value = "/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> deleteFlight(@PathVariable Long id){
        return flightService.deleteFlight(id);
    }

}
```

Comment: `But since then, even during post requests JPA` What do you mean by that? You need to be more clear as to what exactly you are experiencing. Also without any kind of service/controller layer to show, it is hard to under what really goes on here.

Comment: @akortex I am sorry about being vague. I have added a few specifics and also shared the controller class. If there's anything else you want to know, please comment. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Where is the problem ? You don't initialize availableSeats in the default constructor so it's value is 0. That's basic Java SE.

Comment: I totally see what you are saying here. But it's not completely clear to me. JPA uses these constructors behind the scenes, so I was under the impression that they would use the constructor with arguments instead of default constructor. So do the entities need both constructors (arg & default)? Also do I need to initialize availableSeats in both constructors?

Comment: JPA uses only the default constructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring's controller uses default(zero argument) constructor for object creation and then uses it's setter methods for setting the values in the object. You cannot expect for spring to use parameterized constructor.
So if you need to set some default values then do it in zero argument constructor.

Answer (score 0):

As @grigouille pointed out in the comments, JPA only uses default constructor. Hence, availableSeats should have been initialised in the default constructor too.